# Equality of coinductive types

Tags: agda, dependent-type, coinduction, cubical-type-theory

I use the usual coinductive definition of the M-type.

```
record M (S : Set) (Q : S → Set) : Set where
  coinductive
  constructor sup-M
  field
    shape : S
    pos : Q shape → M S Q
open M
```

Assume `Y, S : Set`, `Q : S → Set`, `s : S`, `h : Q s → Y`. I define a function `β` going into `M` by co-pattern matching.

```
β : Y → M S Q
shape (β y) = s
pos (β y) = β ∘ h
```

I would now like to show that any other function `β̃` defined as above is equal to `β`.

```
β-unique : (β̃ : Y → M S Q) → 
           ((y : Y) → (shape (β̃ y) , pos (β̃ y)) ≡ (s , β̃ ∘ h)) →
           β̃ ≡ β
```

I am trying to do this by co-pattern matching as below.

```
shape (β-unique β̃ β̃-comm i y) = fst (β̃-comm y i)
pos (β-unique β̃ β̃-comm i y) q = {!!}
```

Showing the shapes are equal is straightforward: this is given by the first component of `β̃-comm`. Showing the positions are equal involves making use of the below path given by the second component of `β̃-comm`,

```
pos-path : PathP (λ i → Q (fst (β̃-comm y i)) → M S Q) (pos (β̃ y)) (β̃ ∘ h)
pos-path i = snd (β̃-comm y i)
```

and recursively calling `β-unique` to show `(β̃ ∘ h)` is the same as `β ∘ h`. I'm having trouble composing this reasoning in Cubical Agda, mainly because the variable `q` has type `Q (fst (β̃-comm y i))` which is in terms of a path variable `i`. Trying to prove this without introducing any path variables leads me to non-termination errors.

> How can I complete my proof β-unique?

Many thanks for reading!